# Reactor Kafka - Parallel consumption from multiple topics?

Tags: multithreading, apache-kafka, reactor, reactor-kafka

TL;DR; Do I need a per-topic `KafkaReceiver` instance if I want to process the messages from separate topics in parallel and the message processing time from different topics is different?

I am experimenting with 1 `KafkaReceiver` subscribed to 5 topics, each having 1 partition.

It can happen that processing of the messages coming from a particular topic slows down. To avoid pausing the consumer, since processing of the messages from other topics works fine, I group messages per topic and do processing on separate threads. It looks something like this:

```
...
scheduler = Schedulers.newParallel("P", 5);
...
flux.log()
    .groupBy(m -> m.receiverOffset().topicPartition())
    .flatMap(partitionFlux -> partitionFlux.publishOn(scheduler)
        .map(this::transform)
        .map(this::process)
    .doOnError(throwable -> {
        log.error("Ups!", throwable);
    })
    .subscribe();
```

What I would like to prevent is filling up the memory by constantly consuming messages and I am not sure when the `KafkaConsumer#poll` is triggered.

Since I am new to `reactor-kafka` I am guessing that `poll` happens when `request(NNN)...` is logged and it seems that the thread from the scheduler pool is invoking it:

```
[            P-4] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.2                 : request(256)
[            P-4] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.2                 : onNext(ConsumerRecord...
[            P-4] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.2                 : onNext(ConsumerRecord...
[            P-4] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.2                 : onNext(ConsumerRecord...
```

I assume here that the processing thread(P-4) is saying "I can process more!!!".

Sometimes I get:

```
...
[r-coordinator-3] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.2                 : onNext(ConsumerRecord(...
[r-coordinator-3] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.2                 : onNext(ConsumerRecord(...
[r-coordinator-3] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.2                 : onNext(ConsumerRecord(...
...
```

where `r-coordinator-3` is the thread that use to do processing before `.publishOn` was added to the pipeline.

1. Does `poll` happen when `request(NNN)...` is logged?
2. Why is it the case that sometimes `P-4` and sometimes `r-coordinator-3` is logging the `onNext` event?
3. If `poll` is invoked when the processing thread, e.g. `P-4`, is ready to further process messages, will `poll` fetch messages from all the topics and eventually cause out of memory error? In "1 KafkaReceiver - 5 topics" example, thread `P-4` might be processing quickly and it might be frequently calling `poll` while other threads would fill up their queues if poll fetches from all the topics and they are slow.
4. Is my only option in this use case to use `KafkaReceiver` per topic?